# getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.install4j.script.I4jScript_Internal_36 while updationg install4j on linux machine

Tags: linux, install4j

Currently I am using version 6.1.5 of install4j on Linux. When i am checking for updates, I am getting following error:

Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.install4j.script.I4jScript_Internal_36
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.Install4jClassLoader.loadClass(Install4jClassLoader.java:81)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl.runScript(ContextImpl.java:187)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl.runScript(ContextImpl.java:182)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl.checkGroupCondition(ContextImpl.java:197)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.ScreenNavigator.forward(ScreenNavigator.java:154)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.ScreenNavigator.findNextScreenConfig(ScreenNavigator.java:60)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.handleCommand(Controller.java:213)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.start(Controller.java:94)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Application.runApplication(Application.java:71)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Application.main(Application.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:65)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.main(UnixLauncher.java:57)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This compiled script class is contained in the JAR file `.install4j\user.jar`. From your error message, it would seem that that JAR file has been deleted or replaced with a version that is not compatible with the contents of `.install4j\i4jparams.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

One reason can be that the .jar file is excluded from your build path.
To make sure that's not the case and to correct that, go in install4j:

1. "Files" (in the left selection bar)
2. "Define distribution tree"
3. "Content of [your distribution tree]"
4. "Excluded files and directories"
5. you will see a list of files. The excluded ones are checked. Make sure that the .jar file is unchecked.

[image of these five steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9e01p.png)